# how to increase iframe width on onclick of image.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am getting troubled when I click on show/hide image `div_20` will be hide & width of iframe will be increased but space of `div_20` will be blank space & iframe width will be increased in horizontal. Please give me guidance related to this problem.

I have tried following jquery code for show/hide left menus.

```js
$('#mainmenu').toggle(
  function()
  {
    $('#ifrm').css("width", '100%')
    $('#div_20').css("width", '5%')
    $('#ifrm').css("margin-left", '0')
  }, function() {
    $('#ifrm').css("width", '83.5%')
    $('#div_20').css("width", '17%')
    $('#ifrm').css("margin-left", '0%')
  });
```

```html
   <div  id="mainmenu">
     <a> 
        <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i>
    </a> 
   </div>
   <div  id="div_20">
    //list of menus

    </div>

   <iframe id="ifrm" src="dashboard.php" name="ifrm2" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

Comment: @Mohamed  I have tried but width of iframe not be changed.

Comment: when i chnged .css to .attr then nothing happen.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/16w97uvj/1/

Comment: Look at this too http://jsfiddle.net/16w97uvj/2/

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef   When i click on justifying icon menu will be hiding and width of iframe also increase but width of iframe will increase from 'margin-left=17.5' width I want to increase width from 'margin-left=0'

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/16w97uvj/3/

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef tried but not getting solution.

Comment: Ok just add !important; to width : 100% !important;  http://jsfiddle.net/16w97uvj/4/ and add it for margin-left if needed

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef 50% problem solve but one problem is that iframe width will be 100% and margin-left will not be 0%

Comment: $("#ifrm").css({width: <your pixels>}) should work

Comment: @ZigmaEmpire I want only in percentage.

Comment: then make display table or display block, work with position absolute if needed, $("#ifrm").css({"width": <your percentage>, "display": "table", "position": "absolute"})..... but your parent tags should allow it first

Answer (score 0):

If you can specify what lies within #div_20 this will help, thus:

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <a><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i></a> 
</div>
<div id="div_20">
    <ul>
      <li>Menu1</li>
      <li>Menu1</li>
      <li>Menu1</li>
      <li>Menu1</li>
      <li>Menu1</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<iframe id="ifrm" src="dashboard.php" name="ifrm2" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

You can then use the following jQuery code

```
var newWIdth;
$('#ifrm').css({ marginLeft: 0 });
$('#div_20').height(100);       
$('#mainmenu > a').on('click', function()
{
    $('#div_20 > ul').toggle();
    newWIdth = $('#ifrm').width()+10;
    $('#ifrm').width(newWIdth);
    $('#ifrm').css({ marginLeft: 0 });
});
```

Comment: In 'div20' <ul><li>Menu1</li><li>Menu1</li><li>Menu1</li><li>Menu1</li><li>Menu1</li></ul>

Comment: OK. I've edited the solution. Hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried your code but iframe will not get 'margin-left=0'

Comment: I have added to code to set the margin-left to 0. Hope that helps.

Comment: when i tried margin-left code then it shows following error            TypeError: $(...).style is undefined